# How do I make a dynamic pivot macro?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have recorded a macro for inserting a pivot. Since the macro is recorded it works fine with the specific excel sheet. But I want to generalize it such that it works on all sheets irrespective of the number of rows. So I want to select the 'N' column starting from 'N6' to the last filled cell. This I did using,
 `Range(Range("N5"), Range("N5").End(xlDown)).Select`

But I want a dynamic destination for the pivot. It should be a couple of rows below the last filled rows in the sheet. How do I do that?

```
Sub Macro2()

Range("N6:N31").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R6C14:R31C14", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R38C11", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(38, 11).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("BREAK TYPE")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("BREAK TYPE"), "Count of BREAK TYPE", xlCount

Range("K38").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("BREAK TYPE")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

Comment: what Range do you want to have inside the PivotTable ? from which Worksheet ? and also, what dimensions are dynamic ? rows? columns ?

Comment: In the column Break Type, I want the range to start from 'N6' and continue till the last filled row in the same column. The pivot should be on the same worksheet 'Sheet1' but it should appear a little below the last row.

Comment: Range from N6 all the way down to last filled cell is : `Range("N6:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: it is not recommended to put the Pivot table under the sourcedata, as if the souredata is dymanic, and future records are added it wiil overlap the PivotTable and will result in an Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below checks for last row with data in Column N, then it checks if there is already a Pivot Table in "Sheet1".

If there is, it just refreshes the Pivot cache, according to updated Data.
If there isn't, it creates a PivotTable (2 rows under - Not Recommended).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()

Dim shtPivot                        As Worksheet
Dim PivotSrc_Range                  As Range
Dim PvtTbl                          As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                        As PivotCache
Dim lastRow                         As Long

' modify to your Sheet name that holds the Pivot source data
Set shtPivot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With shtPivot
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    ' setting dynamic Range in Column N
    Set PivotSrc_Range = Range("N6:N" & lastRow)

    ' for debug
    Debug.Print PivotSrc_Range.Address
End With

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PivotSrc_Range, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = shtPivot.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Sheet1" sheet, start 3 rows below your last line with data
    Set PvtTbl = shtPivot.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=shtPivot.Range("N" & lastRow + 3), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    ' modify the name in brackets according to your Pivot Fields
    With PvtTbl.PivotFields("BREAK TYPE")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("BREAK TYPE"), "Count of BREAK TYPE", xlCount

Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in Sheet1)
    PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    PvtTbl.RefreshTable
End If

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you not recommend adding the pivot in the same worksheet. Should I add the pivot in a new sheet?

Comment: I think it's better , or a few columns to the right (if you won't get anymore columns)

Comment: Hi Shai, your code was running fine till I was using it on a individual file. But when I am trying to save it in he PERSONAL.XLSB for future use and then run it then I am getting an error, i.e. Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.
The line it is highlighting is this one:

Set PvtTbl = shtPivot.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=shtPivot.Range("N" & lastRow + 10), TableName:="PivotTable1")